# GridView Vertical ScrollBar Postion Align to Container

Tags: xaml, gridview, uwp

I have a `GridView` declaration in XAML :

```
    <Grid x:Name="ContainerGrid">
       <GridView x:Name="GridView" ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModel}"
       VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
          <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <Grid Margin="8" MaxWidth="340">
                <!-- removed for clarity -->
               </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
          </GridView.ItemTemplate>
       </GridView>
    </Grid>
```

This `GridView` will displayed it's items in columns.

[image: GridView]

The problem is ScrollBar shown in right after column last column in row (**1** in screenshot).

I want this `ScrollBar` align to it's `Container` **ContainerGrid** (**2** in screenshot).

I set `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` `VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"` in `GridView` but result is still the same.

UPDATE : My mistake, it's turn out that I have set `HorizontalAlignment="Left"` in parent container for `Grid` **ContainerGrid**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake, it's turn out that I have set `HorizontalAlignment="Left"` in parent container for `Grid` **ContainerGrid**.

Answer (score 0):

And have you tried with HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ? For me the stretch seems to be on the horizontal axis. Eventually, can you check with the Live Visual Tree (on Visual Studio) if there is any padding around the gridview ?

Comment: I actually want to ask if there is any padding around the `ContainerGrid`, cause OP's code works fine by me.

Comment: I will check visual tree, and post the result here, thanks.